# Firefox doesn't accept my width and height specifications on a div with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://henrybuiltfurniture.com/new/furniture.html

The css for a div that contains images that isn't showing up as having any width:

```
.wide{
    width:5000px;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
}
```

the html for div:

```
<div class="wide">
    <div id="limiter1" class="limiter"><div class="cont"><img src="1.jpg" id="img1" onload="bump();" class="slideimage" alt="img1"/></div></div>
    <div id="limiter2" class="limiter"><div class="cont"><img src="2.jpg" id="img2" onload="bump();" class="slideimage"/></div></div>
    <div id="limiter3" class="limiter"><div class="cont"><img src="3.jpg" id="img3" onload="bump();" class="slideimage"/></div></div>
    <div id="limiter4" class="limiter"><div class="cont"><img src="4.jpg" id="img4" onload="bump();" class="slideimage"/></div></div>
    <div id="limiter5" class="limiter"><div class="cont"><img src="5.jpg" id="img5" onload="bump();" class="slideimage"/></div></div>
</div>
```

The div shows up just fine on safari and chrome. How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? And if you're expecting it to be visible, `display:none;` is not going to help.

Comment: When I inspect your elements, they all got 0px height (both "wide" container and "limiter" children divs). Do you see any possible reason for that? How is their height calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following CSS.I guess this could be the reason for the image not showing:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Also you have `display:none;` set in your CSS.Remove it if you are wanting to display your `div` containing images.

Comment: accepting when able. the display:none is intentional and is reverted later

Comment: @maxhud I tested the CSS in my answer in the `style editor` of mozilla and it worked.So i am 100% sure this is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what is causing it :-

```
.wide div.limiter{
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
            }
```

Should be replaced with :-

```
.wide div.limiter{              
                    position: absolute;
                }
```